# Maximum possible value of $P(10)$

Tags: polynomials

The real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are each less than or equal to $12$.  The polynomial $$P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$ satisfies $P(2)=2$, $P(4)=4$ and $P(6)=6$. Find the maximum possible value of $P(10)$.

What I did was first I used the given information to get $3$ equation in $a, b,c,d$. Then I obtained values of $a$, $b$, $c$ in terms of $d$.  Then using these values, I found $P(10)$ in terms of $d$ and substituted $d=12$. But I couldn't arrive at the answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that maximizing $d$ will not necessarily maximize $P(10)$ since $a$, $b$, and $c$ all depend on $d$.  It's possible that maximizing $d$ will, for example, make $a$ so small that, for example, $P(10)$ would be larger if $d$ were, for example, $10$.  For example.

Comment: Please show the expression you got for $P(10)$ as a function of $d$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the system

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 8 a+4 b+2 c+d=2 \\
 64 a+16 b+4 c+d=4 \\
 216 a+36 b+6 c+d=6 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

we get

$b = -12 a, c = 1 + 44 a, d = -48 a$

with the constraints

$-12 a\leq 12\land 44 a+1\leq 12\land -48 a\leq 12$

which give the limitation

$-\frac{1}{4}\leq a\leq \frac{1}{4}$

Therefore plugging in the polynomial we have

$P(x)=a x^3-12 a x^2+(44 a+1) x-48 a$

and $P(10)=2 (96 a+5)$

which is maximum for $a=\frac{1}{4}$

and $P(10)=58$

Hope this is useful

Answer (score 1):

$P(x)=x+a(x-2)(x-4)(x-6)$ because $2,4,6$ are roots of the cubic $P(x)-x$, whose leading coefficient is $a$.

Therefore, $P(x)=a x^3 - 12 a x^2 + (44 a + 1) x - 48 a$.

Since the coefficients are all at most $12$, we need
$$
a \le 12, \quad -12 a \le 12, \quad 44a+1 \le 12, \quad -48a \le 12
$$
Therefore,
$
-\frac14 \le a \le \frac14
$.

Now, $P(10)=10+192a$, whose maximum value is $58$, attained at $a=\frac14$.

Comment: A very good thought

Comment: It's wrong because $P(x)=a x^3-12 a x^2+44 a x-48 a+x$ has coefficients greater than $12$ for $a=12$

Comment: @Raffaele, you're quite right! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you find $P(10)$ as a function of $d$ you want to find the value of $d$ that maximizes $P(10)$ subject to the restriction $d \le 12$, so take the derivative with respect to $d$, set to zero, solve for $d$.  Then compare with the $P(10)$ that comes from $d=12$ because the optimum may come at the boundary.

Comment: I suspect that $P(10)$ will be linear in $d$. So the boundary point ($d=12$) would achieve the extremum.

Comment: @MathLover:  I asked OP to give his expression.

Comment: Math lover is right I got a linear expression in d for P(10)

Comment: @Greninja:  if the coefficient of $d$ is positive, then you would find the maximum $P(10)$ at $d=12$.  What is the problem plugging in $d=12$?